# how to prevent for loop from using space as deliminator, bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, grep, cut

I am trying to right a bash script to do multiple checks and searches for a CMS my company uses. I trying to implement a function for a user to be able to search for a certain macro call and the function return all the files that contain the call, the line the macro is called on, and the actual code in the macro call. What I have seems to be getting screwed up by the fact I am using a for loop to format the output. Here's the snippet of the script I am working on:

```
    elif [ "$choice" = "2" ]
then
    echo -e "\n What macro call are we looking for $name?"
    read macrocall
    for i in $(grep -inR "$macrocall" $sitepath/templates/macros/); do 
    file=$(echo $i | cut -d\: -f1 | awk -F\/ '{ print $NF }')
    line=$(echo $i | cut -d\: -f2)
    calltext=$(echo $i | cut -d\: -f3-)
    echo -e "\nFile: $file"
    echo -e "\nLine: $line"
    echo -e "\nMacro Call from file: $calltext"
    done
fi
```

the current script runs the first few fields until it gets a a space and then everything gets all screwy. Anybody have any idea how I can have the for loops deliminator to be each result of the grep? any suggestions would be helpful. Let me know if any of you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the internal field separator [`$IFS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-IFS) (which is normally set to space, tab and newline) to just newline to get around this problem:

```
IFS="\n"
```

Comment: Well that was easy enough. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this would be more like:

```
printf "\n What macro call are we looking for %s?" "$name"
read macrocall

# ensure globbing is off and set IFS to a newline after saving original values
oSET="$-"; set -f; oIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'

awk -v macrocall="$macrocall" '
    BEGIN    { lc_macrocall = "\\<" tolower(macrocall) "\\>" }
    tolower($0) ~ lc_macrocall {
        file=FILENAME
        sub(/.*\//,"",file)
        printf "\n%s\n", file
        printf "\n%d\n", FNR
        printf "\nMacro Call from file: %s\n", $0
    }
' $(find "$sitepath/templates/macros" -type f -print)

# restore original IFS and globbing values
IFS="$oIFS"; set +f -"$oSET"
```

This solves the problem of having spaces in your file names as originally requested, but also handles globbing characters in your file names, and the various typical `echo` issues.